# How to operate on part of line only

Tags: sed

How do I make sed operate on specific parts of a line only? And, on the contrary, how do I make sed not work on specific parts of a line?

Examples:

```
"A a A a ( A a ) A ( a A ) a"
```

How do I, for instance, replace all the `A`s with `T`s *only* between the `(` and `)` to obtain:

```
"A a A a ( T a ) A ( a T ) a"
```

And given next example input:

```
"F f F f ( F f ) F ( f F ) f"
```

How do I, for instance, replace all the `F`s with `X`s but *not* between the `(` and `)` to
obtain:

> "X f X f ( F f ) X ( f F ) f"

I searched Google but found nothing usable. I guess it's a general question about sed. The problem is reducible to general sed "templates", I hope.

1. having FROM and TO then operate between them only (on all occurrences on given line)
2. having FROM and TO operate anywhere else than between them...
3. special case when FROM and TO are the same (between " and " or "FOO" and "FOO" etc.)
   for both 1. and 2.

It should work with any operation, not just substitution, but also with printing etc., like printing everything between strings "FOO" and "BAR" in string.

```
"1 2 3 BAR a b c FOO d e f BAR g a h FOO i j k BAR l m n FOO o p q"
```

The result will be

```
" d e f  i j k "
```

So, general examples on how to do it would be highly appreciated. It also seems that this question is quite common, but no good howto is found on the Google yet. I also guess this
would be quite challenging to answer. Please, also do no give any hints on how to do it
using Perl, AWK or whatever else than sed. This question is really a sed-only question.

Comment: I tried my best. My idea was to split the line into pieces by the FROM and TO (somehow) and then "somehow" (I do not know how yet) to operate either on even or odd parts only or something alike. If I knew how to do it, I would not asked here. And, it's very likely my idea of splitting may be wrong. It's quite difficult and I used to use sed for simple tasks only before.

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer.

Insert newlines to separate the segments then use the newlines, line beginning (`^`), line ending (`$`) and delimiter characters (parentheses in this case) as anchors and loop. The added newlines are removed at the end.

```
$ echo "A a A a ( A a ) A ( a A ) a" |
    sed 's/([^)]*)/\n&/g; 
         :a; 
           s/\(\n([^)]*\)A\([^)]*)\)/\1T\2/;
         ta; 
         s/\n//g'
A a A a ( T a ) A ( a T ) a
$ echo "F f F f ( F f ) F ( f F ) f" | 
    sed 's/(/\n(/g; 
         s/)/)\n/g; 
         :a; 
           s/\([^(]*\)F\([^)]*\(\n\|$\)\)/\1X\2/g; 
         ta; 
         s/\n//g'
X f X f ( F f ) X ( f F ) f
$ echo "1 2 3 BAR a b c FOO d e f BAR g a h FOO i j k BAR l m n FOO o p q" | 
    sed 's/^/BAR/;
         s/$/FOO/;
         s/FOO/&\n/g;
         s/BAR/\n&/g;
         s/BAR[^\n]*\n//g;
         s/[^\n]*FOO\n//g;
         s/\n//g'
 d e f  i j k
```

Comment: Thank you. Give me some time to go through it, please.

Comment: What if I wanted to replace, say, everything AROUND sections surrounded by "[" and "]" characters as it is in regular expression? The task is similar to transforming normal regex (where all the "()[]{}|+?" character have no need to be escaped) to, say, grep or sed expression, where special chars must be escaped. I mean, given, say, next sed expression without escaped the characters that must be escaped in sed syntax due to make them special characters I would like to apply on the AROUND space next sed program: "s/\\([][(){}|+?]\\)/\\\1/g". The input would be same "s/([][(){}|+?])/\\\1/g".

Comment: I maintain database of BASIC POSIX regexes in form where "^.[$()|*+?{\" characters need to be escaped with "\" to make them "non-special" (man 7 regex). I need a script to transform these regular expressions into a form I need at given moment, say the grep(1) form. Then I need it as, say, sed(1) form, or vi editor form etc. Manually transforming the regexes is painful and now the db have grown to quite a huge size. To transform all the regexes manually, even in such a clever editor as vi is, is painful. I need a script for that task, which was my original motivation for asking this question.

Comment: @hex: Take a look at [`txt2regex`](http://aurelio.net/soft/txt2regex/). Since `sed` doesn't do look-arounds, the kind of replacement you're asking about regarding nesting parentheses and brackets would be next to impossible. They could probably be done in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/\(([^)]*\)A/\1T/;ta' file # for case 1

sed ':a;s/\(([^)]*\)F/\1\n/;ta;y/F\n/TF/' file  # for case 2
```

For case 1 use a loop to substitute `A`'s inside brackets to `T`'s.

For case 2 use the same as above to change `F`'s inside brackets to newlines, then translate `F`'s and newlines to `X`'s and `F`'s respectively.

Case 3 is a little more involved but can be done in 2 substitute commands:

```
sed -r 's/FOO|BAR/\n&/g;s/[^\n]*(\nBAR[^\n]*)*(\nFOO([^\n]*)\nBAR)?(\nFOO[^\n]*$)?/\3/g' file
```

First prefix each `FOO` and `BAR` strings with newlines. Then look for all combinations of `FOO` and `BAR` and only keep the strings between `FOO` and `BAR`. The newlines allow the use of the negative class to simplify the procedure.